# DataSet - How to retrieve values from grouped columns?

Tags: reporting-services

I have SQL which return data:

```
SELECT
dbo.TOWARY.TWR_NUMER AS INDEKS,
dbo.TOWARY.TWR_NAZWA AS NAZWA,
dbo.SL_JM.SLJM_KOD AS JM,
SUM (dbo.WAZENIA.WZN_ILOSC * dbo.WZN_CNY.WZNCNY_NETTO) / SUM (dbo.WAZENIA.WZN_ILOSC) AS CENA,
DATEPART(yyyy, dbo.ZAKUPY.ZKP_DATA_ZAKUPU) AS ROK,
dbo.MAGAZYNY.MG_KOD AS MG_KOD,
dbo.MAGAZYNY.MG_NAZWA AS MG_NAZWA,

ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
        PARTITION BY
        dbo.TOWARY.TWR_NUMER
       ORDER BY
       dbo.TOWARY.TWR_NUMER,
       DATEPART(yyyy, dbo.ZAKUPY.ZKP_DATA_ZAKUPU) DESC
) AS NUMER
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZY8J.png)
[ROK] - Year the number of columns is variable

I grouped the columns by: YEAR [ROK]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvRen.png)

I want to divide the years between them, e.g.: 2021/2020 2022/2021 2023/2022 (...)
for rows (Example 20001):
0,61 / 0,64
0,74 / 0,64
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2fjy.png)

DataSet - How to retrieve values from grouped columns?
But i don't know how take value from Column (Year)?

%First / Last
=(First(Fields!CENA.Value, "INDEKS")-Last(Fields!CENA.Value, "INDEKS"))/Last(Fields!CENA.Value, "INDEKS")

The problem is described in the post

Comment: Please don't post data or text as images. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `Previous()`. You must a scope that is the name of your `Column Group`, in your case it might be called `ROK` but check by looking at the column groups below the main design pane. The name is case sensitive and must be in double quotes.

So you expression might look something like this...

```
=(SUM(Fields!CENA.Value)) / (PREVIOUS(SUM(Fields!CENA.Value), "ROK")
```

This will not handle divide be zero errors etc. but it should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/asqFA.png

My code with support Errors:

```
=IIF(
    (Previous(Sum(Fields!CENA.Value), "ROK") = 0 OR Sum(Fields!CENA.Value) = 0),
    "-",
    (
    Sum(Fields!CENA.Value) -
    IIF(
    Previous(Sum(Fields!CENA.Value), "ROK") = 0,
    Sum(Fields!CENA.Value),
    Previous(Sum(Fields!CENA.Value), "ROK")
    ))
    /
    IIF(
    Previous(Sum(Fields!CENA.Value), "ROK") = 0,
    Sum(Fields!CENA.Value),
    Previous(Sum(Fields!CENA.Value), "ROK")
    ))
```

And color:

```
=IIF(
(Previous(Sum(Fields!CENA.Value), "ROK") = 0 OR Sum(Fields!CENA.Value) = 0),
"Blue",
IIF
((
Sum(Fields!CENA.Value) -
IIF(
Previous(Sum(Fields!CENA.Value), "ROK") = 0,
Sum(Fields!CENA.Value),
Previous(Sum(Fields!CENA.Value), "ROK")
)) >=0.01,"Red","LimeGreen"
))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).